# 3 Monitors with laptop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have a [Asus VivoBook S400CA](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS_VivoBook_S400CA/) , it has 1x VGA and 1x HDMI port. Can I connect 2 monitors to these ports and use all 3 monitors(1 Internal, 2 External) ? And I want to stretch the screen and not clone it.

cpu : core i5 3337U@1.8 GHz
ram : 8GB ddr3 1600
vga : Intel HD 4000 (Approx. Total Memory : 1792MB , according to dxdiag)

Comment: what OS do you have?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Win8.1 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very likely yes!
the [internal Intel graphics](http://ark.intel.com/de/products/72055/Intel-Core-i5-3337U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-2_70-GHz) supports it.

> `#` of Displays Supported:    3